# Image Processing on a micro-controller

Tags: image, microcontroller, fpga

I'm interested in starting a hobbyist project, where I do some image processing by interfacing HW and SW. I am quite a newbie to this. I know how to do some basic image processing in Matlab using the existing image processing commands.

I personally enjoy working with HW and wanted to a combination of HW/SW to be able to do this. I've read articles on people using FPGAs and just basic FPGAs/micro-controllers to go about doing this.

Here is my question: can someone recommend languages I should consider that will help me with interfacing on a PC? I image, the SW part would essentially be a GUI and is place-holder for all the processing that is done on the HW. Also in-terms of selecting the HW and realistically considering what I could do on the HW, could I get a few recommendations on that too?

Any recommendations will be appreciated!

EDIT: I read a few of the other posts saying requirements are directly related to knowing what kind of image processing one is doing. Well initially, I want to do finger print recognition. So filtering and locating unique markers in the image etc.

Comment: What is the approximate size (in bytes) of the image you plan on processing? And do you have any requirements regarding speed? (mostly related to how the interface should be done)

Comment: In terms of size, I was approximating it to be about 100 kilo bytes. Regarding speed, I'm not too picky since it is a learning experience. Do you have any links I read up on that recommend the technical consequences/advantages/dis-advantages of choosing a specific interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what you are familiar with, how you plan on doing the interface between FPGA and PC, and generally the scale of what you want to do. Examples could be:

1. A fast system could for instance consist of a [Xilinx SP605
   board](http://www.xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/EK-S6-SP605-G.htm), using the PCI Express interface to quickly transfer image
   data between PC and FPGA. For this, you'd need to write a device
   driver (in C), and a user-space application (I've done this in
   C++/Qt).
2. A more realistic hobbyist system could be a [Xilinx SP601
   board](http://www.xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/EK-S6-SP601-G.htm), using Ethernet to transfer data - you'd then just have to
   write a simple protocol (possibly using raw sockets (no TCP/UDP) to
   make the FPGA side Ethernet simpler), which can be done in basically
   any language offering network access (there's a Xilinx reference
   design for the SP605 demonstrating this).
3. The simplest and cheapest solution would be an FPGA board with a
   serial connection - you probably wouldn't be able to do any
   "serious" image processing with this, but it should be enough for
   very simple proof-of-concept stuff, although the smaller FPGA devices used o these boards typically do not have much on-board memory available.

But again, it all depends on what you actually want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sonicwave. That was quite helpful. Do you have any recommendations on text-books that explain image processing on FPGAs?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of - but I know a couple of guys who wrote their masters thesis in the field a couple of years ago. The thesis is available here: http://covil.sdu.dk/publications/AknLbwjMaster.pdf - it might give you a starting point, even though it's using custom boards and a direct firewire interface to the camera. If you want to do more advanced stuff, there's always Xilinx' system generator, which allows you to synthesize Matlab algorithms onto special DSP slices in certain FPGAs - but I've never used it myself though, so I know it exists and not much more...

Comment: Thanks sonicwave. Maybe I'm reading into your post, but it seems to me that you don't agree with using that kind of interface. Why is that?

Comment: The master thesis I linked to put the FPGA vision processing between the Firewire-based camera and PC. And while Firewire is the best solution in that particular case, there are far easier solutions (such as those listed above) if you are only interfacing to a PC.